# What happens to a file in a sambashare hosted on Ubuntu when i access it in windows and configure it to be hidden?

Tags: windows, files, samba

What happens to files in Samba share when the host is Ubuntu and the client is windows when I make the files "hidden" in windows?

I hide some files to make it look cleaner, but I don't want the actual files to be changed in any way, maybe there's a better way of doing it.

Comment: Good question. By experiment, the file and it's permissions,  as seen via linux is unchanged, but is indeed hidden when looking via windows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)